# How to get erc20 contract deploy time / block number

Tags: erc-20, blocks

I am building a framework for ERC20 tokens.

Aim is to scan all events (Transfer and Approve) generated by ERC20 contract, for which I am using web3.js **[getPastEvents](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#getpastevents)**.

I have set the **toBlock** to **web3.eth.getBlockNumber()** i.e. latest block

Now, to avoid scanning unnecessary blocks, I have to set **fromBlock** option. Can someone explain how to get **block's number** of the block in which erc20 token was deployed?

Answer (score 2):

There is no fast/elegant way to get the first transaction to an ethereum address/contract.

I will avoid scanning each block from the beginning.

What I will do is start from the top of the chain ( latest block) 10,000 blocks at a time and read all the events.

Once I get 0 events in the last 10,000 blocks I will stop.

That seems to be a working (not very elegant) solution.

Comment: Alternatively you can do a binary search on web3.eth.getCode to find the block it was created in.

Comment: Kindly elaborate, getcode return the compiled code of contract. How to parse the block number from it?

Comment: You can supply a block number to gerCode, so you can do a binary search on the results of that. If it returns bytecode, it's already been created. If it doesn't return bytecode then it hasn't been created yet.

Comment: Got it.  in my method, I am storing the parsed events. If i run sequential/parallel queries for get code till the block where getCode returns nothing, net number of queries will be 2X (getCode + getAllEvents). your solution is better in terms of network data being returned, but for my use case it will make the script heavier..

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the control of the smart contract, emit a 'Deployed' event in the constructor. Then scan for these events.